# Remove the baby from the womb

Tags: surgery

Is it possible to remove the baby from the womb of a mother to cure the baby of a tumor and putting it back in the womb to be delivered naturally (the baby is 6 months)

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! Can you clarify where the tumor on the baby is? Fetal surgery is definitely a thing; however, I would tend to think that a doctor wouldn't want to operate if it weren't a threat to the baby's life. If you have any questions about what kind of questions you should ask or how to ask them, please feel free to visit the Help Center, here https://biology.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: I would think it would be nearly impossible to remove the fetus from the womb, as it is connected to the placenta, and thus to the mother.  While I'm not a surgeon, I would think using minimally-invasive techniques would give a greater chance of success. See e.g. the Wikipedia article on fetal surgery https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetal_surgery or any other of the ~3.7 million hits on "surgery "in utero"".